# Chandra exiles a card, I play it, it gets exiled again

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I exiled a creature card with [Chandra, Fire Artisan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Fire%20Artisan%5d). I then played it, and it got countered by a card that put it back into exile. Can I play it again?

Answer (score 12):

**No, you can't play it again.**

It's necessary to understand that everything in the game is only an imaginary game *object*. Objects are the things that players actually play with. Cards only *represent* objects; they serve as a reminder that there is an object and what its base properties are.

Whenever an object leaves a game zone (such as exile), it ceases to exist. If that object was represented by a card, a new object is instead created in the zone it moved to. Those new objects have no relation to their previous existence.

That means the *object* you exiled with Chandra is different from the one you cast and was countered, and different yet again from the exiled object put there by the counter. That means you can not cast it again with Chandra, because it's a different object to the one Chandra exiled.

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

There are a few exceptions to this rule, but none apply here.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot play the card from exile, because it wasn't exiled by Chandra.

The `you can play the card this turn` clause only applies when the card is exiled by that ability. If the card goes to the exile zone for any other reason, you may not play it.